# BufferMemory issue with ConversationalRetrievalQAChain in JavaScript/Nodejs

Tags: node.js, next.js, large-language-model, pinecone, langchain-js

I am using Langchain in Nodejs and following the official documentation to save the conversation context using `ConversationalRetrievalQAChain` and `BufferMemory`, and not able to pass the memory object to `ConversationalRetrievalQAChain.fromLLM` as per documentation here: https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/chains/popular/chat_vector_db/.

```
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const stream = new TransformStream();
    const writer = stream.writable.getWriter();
    console.log("Querying Pinecone vector store...");
    const index = client.Index(indexName);
    const queryEmbedding = await new OpenAIEmbeddings().embedQuery(question);

    let queryResponse = await index.query({
      queryRequest: {
        topK: 10,
        vector: queryEmbedding,
        includeMetadata: true,
        includeValues: true,
      },
    });

    if (queryResponse.matches.length) {
      const model = new OpenAI({
        modelName: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        streaming: true,
        temperature: 0,
        openAIApiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY || "",
        callbacks: [
          {
            async handleLLMNewToken(token) {
              await writer.ready;
              await writer.write(encoder.encode(`${token}`));
            },
            async handleLLMEnd() {
              await writer.ready;
              await writer.close();
            },
          },
        ],
      });
      const concatenatedPageContent = queryResponse.matches
        .map((match) => match.metadata.pageContent)
        .join(" ");
      const vectorStore = await PineconeStore.fromDocuments(
        [new Document({ pageContent: concatenatedPageContent })],
        new OpenAIEmbeddings(),
        {
          pineconeIndex: index,
        }
      );
      const chain = ConversationalRetrievalQAChain.fromLLM(
        model,
        vectorStore.asRetriever(),
        {
          memory: new BufferMemory({
            memoryKey: "chat_history", // Must be set to "chat_history"
          }),
        }
      );

      /* Ask it a question */
      const question = "What did the president say about Justice Breyer?";
      const res = await chain.call({ question });
      console.log(res);
      /* Ask it a follow up question */
      const followUpRes = await chain.call({
        question: "Was that nice?",
      });
      console.log(followUpRes);
```

Error: `Argument of type '{ memory: BufferMemory; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ outputKey?: string | undefined; returnSourceDocuments?: boolean | undefined; questionGeneratorTemplate?: string | undefined; qaTemplate?: string | undefined; } & Omit<ConversationalRetrievalQAChainInput, "retriever" | ... 1 more ... | "questionGeneratorChain">'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'memory' does not exist in type '{ outputKey?: string | undefined; returnSourceDocuments?: boolean | undefined; questionGeneratorTemplate?: string | undefined; qaTemplate?: string | undefined; } & Omit<ConversationalRetrievalQAChainInput, "retriever" | ... 1 more ... | "questionGeneratorChain">'.ts(2345)`

Goal: My goal is to save the conversation context over the pdf document.

I am open to other suggestions around my use case. There is very less support for the Langchain with Nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

I had `"langchain": "^0.0.84",` and I was getting the same error

update the package to the latest version, currently `"langchain": "^0.0.127"` and it works

Answer (score 0):

had the same, or at least a very similar problem even with newer langchain version.

error was

```
/langchain/dist/chains/conversational_retrieval_chain.js:116
            throw new Error(`Question key ${this.inputKey} not found.`);
```

my problem was solved by adding the literal `question` as key for the memory.

suggest changing line
FROM

```
const res = await chain.call({ question });
```

TO

```
const res = await chain.call({ question: question });
```

hope it helps.